# Swagger 2 @ApiIgnore properties toggle in config server

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using swagger 2 (2.9.2)  in Sprinngboot app.

**Dependency :**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Code :

```
package com.khan.vaquar.swagger;

import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.or;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("vaquar khan public-api").apiInfo(apiInfo()).select().apis( RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage( "com.khan.vaquar" ) )
                .paths(paths()).build();



    }
    private Predicate<String> paths() {
        return or(regex("/.*"), regex("/.*"));
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("vaquar khan public-api")
                .description("vaquar khan public-api app API reference for developers")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("XXX-YYY-ZZZ.com").contact("info@vkhan.com")
                .license("vaquar khan License").licenseUrl("Licence@vkhan.com").version("1.0").build();
    }

}
```

I have almost 70 different micro service , many are internal and only few 10 micro service are external .

Now inside swagger doc hiding micro service using  @ApiIgnore  ,we ignored 60 in swagger and only displaying 10 external api.

**Problem:**

Now i have requirement that external user can see only 10 micro service  in swagger doc and internal micro service swagger (70) should visible to developers and internal users .

Is there any way we can define in application properties @ApiIgnore for prod and display only 10 and in dev config properties will hide @ApiIgnore

Comment: You can try using @Profile("dev") and use different configurations for different environments.

Comment: How to use annotation in profile properties ,this is my question @apiIgnore is annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go with profiles then you don't need the `@ApiIgnore` annotation(s).

Define a developer profile. For example:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/internal/...")
@Api(value = "/internal/...", description = "Internal stuff")
public class OneOfTheInternalControllers { ... }
```

Now mark all your internal controllers / endpoints with the profile. Finally if you run your application in production mode you don't have to do anything. The `@Profile("dev")` APIs will be hidden. However if you run your application locally or in testing environment, pass the following JVM argument:

`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

If you are using IntelliJ you can pass it in Run/Debug Configurations:

[image]

At the end you should see all your APIs as a developer.