# How to create internal and external documentation in Swagger?

Tags: api, spring-boot, swagger, external, internals

I have a small Spring Boot app and Swagger as an API doc framework. How can I separate endpoints in internal and external?

I found a post for [`swagger-php`](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/415) with tag won't fix.

Is it possible to do it at all?

Comment: It is possible, check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644291/7519419